# share files with users with wordpress

Tags: wordpress, file, share

I'm new to wordpress and I need to create a wordpress that allow the administrators to share information and files with users (word, excel, pdf, images, etc).
Each user will have a password and the files are only shared between the user and the administrator (there's no sharing between users).

Maybe that can be accomplished with a post or page targeted for every user. The user would have to be logged to access the page/post and should be able to add content and files. That way the files and info will be only shared between that user and the admin.

Is this a correct approach or there is a better way to do it?

Thanks
Gonzalo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[WordPress Download Manager](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/download-manager/) helps you in managing, tracking and controlling your downloads in a more efficient way. You can set access levels, you can add/embed downloadable files anywhere in the post by copying and pasting the embed code.

For more info :
 http://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-manage-track-control-file-downloads-wordpress/